# Xcode Ios How should i make my app available to different os's

Tags: ios, xcode

I have made an app and was wondering how I should make it available to different os's.

Should I need to reprogram or is there any another way???

Comment: Is that developed in XCode and Objective-C or Swift?

Answer (score 2):

Different OS in the sense ? Different versions ? Change deployment target in the XCode build settings to the least version that you're looking for. But, some features may or may not work if you choose earlier version. Since, they're added up in the later versions. Hope it helps :) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you develop a native app for iOS using Xcode, It is possible to run only in iOS,
So the answer is "NO" you cannot convert or run a native iOS code or app into different OS.

Still if you looking for single development to target different OS's like android or windows, then there are many third parties SDK in which you should deploy and code your app. E.g Xamarin, Kony Studio etc.

Or you should develop native app targeting each platform separately.